# ERROR: void value not ignored as it ought to be in lambda expression

Tags: c++, gtkmm3

By implementing a Gtk::Scale (slider) I get the error message in the title.
The code throwing that error ist:

```
exampleScale->signal_change_value().connect([=](const Gtk::ScrollType &scrolltype, const double &new_value){
        bool on_my_change_value(GtkScrollType scrollType);
        if(on_my_change_value(GTK_SCROLL_STEP_FORWARD)){
            exampleScale->get_value()+1;
        } else if(on_my_change_value(GTK_SCROLL_STEP_BACKWARD)){
            exampleScale->get_value()-1;
        }

        int qualityValue = int(new_value);
        drawingStatisticalArea->queue_draw();
    });
```

What the code should do: By moving the horizontal slider, the user changes qualityValue sending a queue_draw to the drawingArea.
What have I done wrong?

Comment: `exampleScale->get_value()+1;` looks fishy, and should be no-op like `x+1;`. Maybe you need to call `set_value` with that new value to observe the increment.

Comment: Ok, thx, changed that but getting the same error again

Comment: The compiler tells you exactly where the error occurs. Don't make us guess.

Comment: The `qualityValue` variable seems kind of pointless.

Comment: The compiler tells me in line with }); required from here and in the slote.h header the void value error with an arrow to the second bracket of (a_1, a_2)

Comment: There's no `(a_1, a_2)` in this code, so this can't be the code you're compiling.

Comment: /usr/include/sigc++-2.0/sigc++/functors/slot.h:254:25: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
  ```254 |                (a_1, a_2);
             |                               ^```

Comment: Did you try reading [the documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Range.html#a67cf10d9f3845a9b9552a5552c1e520e) and noticing that the handler is supposed to return a boolean value?

Comment: So using another function is better instead?

Comment: Using a function with the appropriate type is not just better, it's necessary.